# Matlab parallel computing toolkit local configuration validation failure

Tags: matlab, configuration, parallel-processing

I've just started using the parallel computing toolkit and whenever I call `matlabpool open` I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> matlabpool at 127
The interactive parallel job errored with the following message:

Unable to get version information from job. This probably means
that the job was created in a client MATLAB prior to the R2009a
general release, or that the jobdata files of the job are corrupt
```

My MATLAB version is 2010a and it's a fairly recent install. I have made no changes to configurations before so it should be the default. When I went into the configuration manager and validated the local configuration I got the following results:

```
**Find Resource**: Passed


**Distributed Job**: Failed
    Details:
    Stage: Distributed Job

Status: Failed
Description:  The job in the given stage completed, but reported failed due to a task failure.

Command Line Output: (none)

Error Report:
Unable to get version information from job. This probably means
that the job was created in a client MATLAB prior to the R2009a
general release, or that the jobdata files of the job are corrupt



Debug Log:
LOG FILE OUTPUT:
MATLAB is running in headless mode.  Figure windows will not be displayed.

  To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
  For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

»


**Parallel Job**: Failed
    Details:
Stage: Parallel Job

Status: Failed
Description:  The job in the given stage completed, but reported failed due to a task failure.

Command Line Output: (none)

Error Report:
Unable to get version information from job. This probably means
that the job was created in a client MATLAB prior to the R2009a
general release, or that the jobdata files of the job are corrupt

Unable to get version information from job. This probably means
that the job was created in a client MATLAB prior to the R2009a
general release, or that the jobdata files of the job are corrupt

Unable to get version information from job. This probably means
that the job was created in a client MATLAB prior to the R2009a
general release, or that the jobdata files of the job are corrupt



Debug Log:
LOG FILE OUTPUT:
[0] MATLAB is running in headless mode.  Figure windows will not be displayed.
[2] MATLAB is running in headless mode.  Figure windows will not be displayed.
[1] MATLAB is running in headless mode.  Figure windows will not be displayed.
[1]  
[1]   To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
[1]   For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
[1]  
[1] » [0]  
[0]   To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
[0]   For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
[0]  
[2]  
[2]   To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
[2]   For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.
[2]  
[0] » [2] » 


**Matlabpool**: Skipped
```

I read elsewhere that the command `distcomp.feature( 'LocalUseMpiexec', false )` has worked for some people, but it had no effect for me, with the same tests failing and the same errors reported.

Has anybody come across this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks really weird, I have never seen that failure before (and I probably use the local scheduler way more than most). The only thing I can suggest is that you blow away the entire contents of the local scheduler's `DataLocation`. You might also need to check that the DataLocation isn't pointing to an old location. You could do the following:

```
s = findResource( 'scheduler', 'Configuration', 'local' );
s.DataLocation % navigate to this directory, delete all contents
% now, restart MATLAB
```

If that doesn't help, I'd suggest contacting The MathWorks install support.